# probability and rolling a die(uniform)

Tags: probability

If I rolled 6 different fair six-sided dice,what is the probability that the maximum of the rolls is equal to 5?

My solution so far

Let x =outcome of die~uniform $[1,6]$

$p(X\leq x)=\frac{1}{5}$
 and $F(X)=\frac{x-1}{5}$

Let $y_n$ =maximum of the rolled die

Then $F(y_n)=(\frac{y_n-1}{5})^n$

so $p(y_n=5)=p(y_n \leq 5)-P(y_n\leq 4)=\frac{4}{5}^6*\frac{3}{5}^6=0.215$

correct answer 0.25

Comment: IMO, "maximum of the rolls is equal to $5$" means that at least one of the dice shows $5$... right?

Answer (score 4):

Note that the dice is six-sided,
$$P(X=x)=\frac16$$
$$P(X \leq x) = \frac{x}6$$
$$P(Y \leq y) = \left( \frac{y}{6}\right)^6$$
$$P(Y=5)=\left(\frac56 \right)^6-\left(\frac46 \right)^6 \approx 0.2471\approx 0.25$$

Comment: We've got different results, which means one of us is wrong I suppose...

Comment: true, let's try to figure out where is the error.

Comment: On the other hand, OP's question includes the correct solution, which appears to be yours, so... Personally, I'm under the impression that this question might be ambiguous, see my comment to it...

Comment: I use the same interpretation as yours. $Y=max_i \left\{ X_i \right\}$

Comment: Dunno... kinda hard for me to read here anyways, my Firefox has stopped rendering LaTex from time to time (it goes on and off, not sure how that could even happen)... Let me know if you spot either one of us' error, Tx :)

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion principle is used to compute cardinality of union of sets right? What are those sets in your computation?

Comment: I've run a simple Python script, and your answer of $24.71\%$ is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Probability of getting a max of five on all dice is equal to one minus the probability of getting at least one six, which would be:

$$ 1 - \sum_{k=1}^{6} \binom{6}{k} * \left(\frac{1}{6} \right)^k * \left(\frac{5}{6} \right)^\left(6-k\right) \approx 0.33$$

Probability that at least one 5 appears without a 6 should be:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{6} \binom{6}{k} * \left(\frac{1}{6} \right)^k * \left(\frac{4}{6} \right)^\left(6-k\right) \approx 0.2471$$

Comment: This includes the probability that the maximum value is $4$, $3$, $2$ or $1$ (i.e., the question doesn't say "at most $5$", it says that the largest value has to be $5$).

Comment: Oh, I'm a bit confused now - so should one of the dice always have a 5?

Comment: That's how I understand this question (at least one die shows $5$, and no die shows $6$).

Comment: I've run a simple Python script, and your answer of $24.71\%$ is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In more technical terms, the possible outcomes of a toss of a die can be modeled by the set $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$.

The fairness of this die can be modeled by the symmetric probability space, $S$, on $\Omega$, namely $S = (\Omega, \mathcal{A} = 2^\Omega, P)$, where, for every $E \subseteq \Omega$, $P(E) = \#E/\#\Omega$.

A sequence of six independent tosses of this die is then modeled by the product probability space $\otimes_{i = 1}^6 S = (\Omega', \mathcal{A}', P')$, in which $\Omega' = \Omega^6$, $\mathcal{A}' = \otimes_{i = 1}^6 \mathcal{A} = 2^{\Omega^6}$, and $P' = \otimes_{i = 1}^6 P$, i.e. $P'$ is the unique probability measure on $(\Omega',\mathcal{A}') = \left(\Omega^6, 2^{\Omega^6}\right)$, which assigns to every event $E \subseteq \Omega^6$ of the form $E = E_1\times E_2 \times \cdots \times E_6$, where $E_1, E_2, \dots, E_6 \subseteq \Omega$, the probability $P'(E) = P(E_1)P(E_2)\cdots P(E_6)$.

The event $E$, whose probability we are interested in calculating, is
$$
E := \left\{(\omega_1, \dots, \omega_6) \in \Omega^6\ |\!:\ \max\{\omega_1, \dots, \omega_6\} = 5\right\}.
$$

Since, for every $d\in \{1, 2, \dots, 6\}$ we have:
$$
d = 5 \iff (d\leq 5) \wedge \neg(d\leq 4),
$$
we may represent $E$ as the difference $E = E_1\setminus E_2$ of the two events
$$
\begin{align}
E_1 &:= \left\{(\omega_1, \dots, \omega_6) \in \Omega^6\ |\!:\ \max\{\omega_1, \dots, \omega_6\} \leq 5\right\}, \\
E_2 &:= \left\{(\omega_1, \dots, \omega_6) \in \Omega^6\ |\!:\ \max\{\omega_1, \dots, \omega_6\} \leq 4\right\}.
\end{align}
$$
Note that $E_2 \subseteq E_1$, and, therefore, $P'(E) = P'(E_2) - P'(E_1)$.

Since, for every $(\omega_1, \dots, \omega_6) \in \Omega^6$ and for every $d\in \{1, 2, \dots, 6\}$,
$$
\max\{\omega_1, \dots, \omega_6\} \leq d \iff (\omega_1 \leq d)\wedge\cdots\wedge(\omega_6 \leq d),
$$
we have
$$
E_1 = \left\{(\omega_1, \dots, \omega_6)\in\Omega^6\ |\!:\ (\omega_1 \leq 5)\wedge\cdots\wedge(\omega_6 \leq 5)\right\} = \{1, 2, \dots, 5\}^6,
$$
and, similarly,
$$
E_2 = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}^6.
$$

We finally calculate the probability of the event $E$.
$$
\begin{align}
P'(E) &= P'(E_1) - P'(E_2) \\
&= P'\left(\{1, \dots, 5\}^6\right) - P'\left(\{1, \dots, 4\}^6\right) \\
&= \left(P\left(\{1, \dots, 5\}\right)\right)^6 - \left(P\left(\{1, \dots, 4\}\right)\right)^6 \\
&= \left(\frac{\#\{1, \dots, 5\}}{\#\Omega}\right)^6 - \left(\frac{\#\{1, \dots, 4\}}{\#\Omega}\right)^6 \\
&= \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^6 - \left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^6 \\
&= \frac{427}{1728}.
\end{align}
$$

In conclusion, $P'(E) \approx 0.247$, rounded to the nearest thousandth.